# How do i disable a mouseout event after click with Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

i want to disable a mouseout event after a shape has been clicked and restore it when the user has clicked on another shape. Is it possible ?

My shape is named here "parechoc"

```
parechoc.on('click', function() {
      this.opacity(1);
      layer.draw();
      disable_mouseout = function (){
        parechoc.off('mouseout')
      }


    });
    parechoc.on('mouseout', function() {
     this.opacity(0);
     layer.draw();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: untested code follows!

```
// a variable to save the last clicked shape
var myLastClickedShape;

// a function to turn on the previously 'off' node
// and turn off the currently clicked node
function onClickableClick(node){
    // turn on mouseout stuff for the previously clicked node
    if(myLastClickedShape){
        myLastClickedShape.on('mouseout',function(){
                // do mouseout stuff
        });
    }
    // turn off mouseout for the currently clicked node
    if(node){
        this.off('mouseout');
    }
    myLastClickedShape=node;
}


// call the toggle function as required
parechoc.on('click', function() {
      onClickableClick(this);
      this.opacity(1);
      layer.draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't work

i've made a few change in my code

i've written a function called on click

function MouseClick (){
        onClickableClick(this);
        this.opacity(1);
        layer.draw();          

  }

called this way :

parechoc.on('click', MouseClick);

Firebug returns :

TypeError: this.off is not a function

Comment: Fixed a glitch: `this.off` should be `node.off`. http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Uf9p3/

Comment: That's funny,this is just what i did before reading your comment and it works but still needs tweakings. Thank you @markE